# WordPress in a Subdirectory

Tags: customization, directory, installation

I am trying to install WordPress in a subdirectory. This is a new fresh install. Here is what I did:

Assuming my site is `example.com`, and I wanted to install wordpress in `example.com/wordpress`

A) I created a database on the server

B) I copied all wordpress directories to `example.com/wordpress`

C) I moved index.php from `example.com/wordpress` to `example.com/`

D) I modified the last line of `index.php` from:

`require( dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/wp-blog-header.php' );`

and it got modified into:

`require( dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/wordpress/wp-blog-header.php' );`

E) I modified `wp-config.php`  and updated it in accordance with the required DB name, user name, password, and server name

Now, when I test hat locally, and when I go to `example.com`, I get redirected to the WordPress installation setup page. However, on the live server, I am redirected to `http://www.example.com/wp-admin/install.php` **(notice the missing wordpress folder, the redirect should be to `http://www.new-example.com/wordpress/wp-admin/install.php`)**.

I have done this before, but not sure what is causing the problem. Can you please help? I really ran out of ideas. I tested everything I can think off (including typos), but to no avail. Please help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you followed [all these steps](http://codex.wordpress.org/Giving_WordPress_Its_Own_Directory). It sounds like the `.htaccess` file was not updated correctly.

Comment: Thanks. I did that already. Also, there isn't `.htaccess` file yet, this is a fresh install and `.htaccess` gets created after using wordpress. I doubt this is the problem.

Comment: So is `http://www.example.com/wp-admin/install.php` showing up as a 404 page since `install.php` is a subdirectory?

Comment: Yes, I get a file not found error. Becuse `install.php` is really located in `http://www.example.com/wordpress/wp-admin/install.php`

Comment: I think talking to you helped me solve the problem. I got it to work. All I did is type the URL for installation. So, I typed `http://www.example.com/wordpress/wp-admin/install.php` and it worked. Thanks. :)

Answer (score 0):

You put this code in your subdirectry .htacces

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /newsite/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ – [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /newsite/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```